# How would you sync a Mongo document with an object?

Tags: mongodb

Say that I've got a collection named `MyCollection` with only one document and an object named `MyObject`

```
db.MyCollection.findOne()

{ _id: "23r3d2", xyz: "something", abc: "something else" }
```

MyObject

```
{ xyz: "lalala" }
```

If you do:

```
db.MyCollection.update( db.MyCollection.findOne() , { $set: MyObject } )
```

The resulting `MyCollection` is:

```
{ _id: "23r3d2", xyz: "lalala", abc: "something else" }
```

Which is NOT the same as `MyObject`, the reason being that `$set` will:

1. Set the value of a key if it's already there.
2. Add in a new key and value if the key doesn't already exist.

It will NOT, however,

1. delete keys from the collection if the field does not exist in the object that $set takes as an argument.

How would you code it so that:

`db.MyCollection.findOne()`

```
{ _id: "23r3d2", xyz: "something", abc: "something else" }
```

would become:

```
db.MyCollection.findOne()

{ _id: "23r3d2", xyz: "lalala"}
```

once you put this object in as a parameter somewhere:

```
MyObject

{ xyz: "lalala" }
```

I would like to avoid having to explicitly define fields to exclude.

Comment: Just take set out, use only your object in update

Comment: First, do not embed statements. Also if you just want to replace things you do not use `$set`. Just `db.Collection.update({ _id: "23r3d2" }, MyObject)` Which replaces everything by default. `$set` exists for the exact opposite reason, where you do not want to replace everything.

Comment: @NeilLunn, what exactly do you mean by "embedding statements?"

Comment: I mean do not use `.findOne` as the way to get a document for update "inline" as you have get the document values in a separate line. It's just by chance the shell is evaluating in this way. Not how mongodb works

Comment: Hmmm... can you elaborate on why? This is what I normally use as a selector for Collections that only have (and will only ever have) one document.

Comment: Sure. Try for example to code that way in an asynchronous environment like node.js. It will fail. Depending on the calling semantics of any language being used, then it will likely fail. It really is about setting good habits. When you move to an async environment you will find you need to change a lot of things if you think things should work this way

Comment: What would be the failsafe way of selected and returning as an object the only document in the collection if I'm not using `findOne()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
db.myCollection.update(db.myCollection.findOne(), MyObject);
```

It will keep the same _id but replace the entire object.

Btw, if you have only one element you can search with an empty query: `{}`, instead of `db.myCollection.findOne()`

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulties finding a use case when you would want to have a collection containing a single document. What you probably want is `findAndModify`, e.g.:

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: <document>,
    sort: <document>,
    remove: <boolean>,
    update: <document>,
    new: <boolean>,
    fields: <document>,
    upsert: <boolean>
});
```

Here is a complete [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).